# python GDAL 'GetDriverByName', argument 1 of type 'char const *'

Tags: python, raster, gdal, python-2.7

i want to use python GDAL to convert some rasters files but i take error in the create new tiff image and specific in the line `driver= gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')`

update *:*

python version 2.7 64 bit

GDAL version 2020100

os: windows

i use it and before this version and all work fine
code :

```
inputfile = 'input.tif'
input = gdal.Open(inputfile )
inputProj = input.GetProjection()
inputTrans = input.GetGeoTransform()

referencefile = 'ref.tif'
reference = gdal.Open(referencefile )
referenceProj = reference.GetProjection()
referenceTrans = reference.GetGeoTransform()
bandreference = reference.GetRasterBand(1)
x = reference.RasterXSize
y = reference.RasterYSize


outputfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.tif').name
driver= gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
output = driver.Create(outputfile,x,y,1,bandreference.DataType)
output.SetGeoTransform(referenceTrans)
output.SetProjection(referenceProj)

gdal.ReprojectImage(input,output,inputProj,referenceProj,gdalconst.GRA_Bilinear)
```

error :

```
    return _gdal.GetDriverByName(*args)
TypeError: in method 'GetDriverByName', argument 1 of type 'char const *'
```

update 2:

that error show when i use this limes:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

but that i need it because i use python 2.7

any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: What's your codepage? It looks like your 'GTiff' is being interpreted as unicode or other multibyte and being passed as const wchar_t*.  Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127413/converting-python-string-object-to-c-char-using-ctypes and see if that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you imported `unicode_literals`, you're passing a *unicode* literal to GDAL which is expecting a *string* literal.

So, explicitly cast the `'GTiff'` arg to a `str`.

E.g.

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>> gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Temp\conda\envs\test27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 3019, in GetDriverByName
    return _gdal.GetDriverByName(*args)
TypeError: in method 'GetDriverByName', argument 1 of type 'char const *'
>>> type('GTiff')
<type 'unicode'>
>>> gdal.GetDriverByName(str('GTiff'))
<osgeo.gdal.Driver; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDriverShadow *' at 0x0000000002A9ED80> >
```